# bot not responding to commands after switching to discord.js v14

Tags: discord.js

Recently I tried to update my bot to discordjs v14 since v12 did not support connection to voice channels. now it runs and comes online but it does not respond to any command that is given, it also does not give an error message.

Here is the index.js file

```
const {  Attachment, Message, MessageEmbed , Collection } = require("discord.js");
const { readdirSync , fs} = require("fs");
const { join } = require("path");
const { PREFIX } = require("./config.json");
const { FILE } = require("dns");
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
      GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
      GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
  ],

});

client.login(token);
client.commands = new Collection();
client.prefix = PREFIX;
client.queue = new Map();
const cooldowns = new Collection();
const escapeRegex = (str) => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");


client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.username} ready!`);
  client.user.setActivity(`${PREFIX}help | Serving ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`);
});
client.on("warn", (info) => console.log(info));
client.on("error", console.error);

/**
 * Import all commands
 */
const musiccommandFiles = readdirSync(join(__dirname, "musiccommands")).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
for (const file of musiccommandFiles) {
  const command = require(join(__dirname, "musiccommands", `${file}`));
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

const modcommandFiles = readdirSync('./modcommands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of modcommandFiles) {
    const modcommand = require(`./modcommands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(modcommand.name, modcommand);
};

const extracommandFiles = readdirSync('./extracommands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of extracommandFiles) {
    const extracommand = require(`./extracommands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(extracommand.name, extracommand);
};


client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.guild) return;

  const prefixRegex = new RegExp(`^(<@!?${client.user.id}>|${escapeRegex(PREFIX)})\\s*`);
  if (!prefixRegex.test(message.content)) return;

  const [, matchedPrefix] = message.content.match(prefixRegex);

  const args = message.content.slice(matchedPrefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const command =
    client.commands.get(commandName) ||
    client.commands.find((cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

  if (!command) return;

  if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
    cooldowns.set(command.name, new Collection());
  }

  const now = Date.now();
  const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
  const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 1) * 1000;

  if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
    const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

    if (now < expirationTime) {
      const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
      return message.reply(
        `please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`
      );
    }
  }


})

const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
});

// Using .catch() handler
myPromise.then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

// using .then() handler's second parameter
myPromise.then(
  (result) => { 
      console.log(result);
  },
  (error) => { 
      console.log(error);
  }
);
```

**I've got no clue why this is happening, here is an example of a file given in the kick command file**

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "kick",
  description: "kicks a member",
  execute: async (message , args) => {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Invalid Permissions")
  
  let member = message.mentions.members.first()
  if(!member)
    return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server");
  if(!member.kickable) 
    return message.reply("I cannot kick this user! Do they have a higher role? Do I have kick permissions?");
  
  let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
  if(!reason) reason = "No reason provided";
  
  await member.kick(reason)
    .catch(error => message.reply(`Sorry ${message.author} I couldn't kick because of : ${error}`));

  let kickembed = new MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle(`:white_check_mark: ${member.user.tag} has been kicked`)
   .setFooter(`Action performed by ${message.author.tag}`)
   .setColor('77B255')
  kickembed.setTimestamp();
  message.channel.send(kickembed);

}

  }
```

All the code was working fine when it was v12.5.3 (except the voice related commands).

Comment: You should really do some basic debugging, and check what runs and what does not. E.g. does `messageCreate` fire, is the `commandName` correct, are the command files read, etc?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros using a debugger in vcs gave back nothing, however when I added a ping pong command in the index.js file it gave back a reply without errors. so I assume it has something to do with the way the files are being read. Do you have an suggestion?

Comment: Debugging can be as simple as adding `console.log()`s throughout your procedure, seeing which logs fire and where your procedure produces unexpected values

Comment: i have fixed this current issue, it was fixed by adding **command.execute(message, args);** at the end of index.js file , I am now facing other problems regarding other changes made in v14 of discord.js

Answer (score 0):

Here is what fixed the problem:

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.guild) return;

  const prefixRegex = new RegExp(`^(<@!?${client.user.id}>|${escapeRegex(PREFIX)})\\s*`);
  if (!prefixRegex.test(message.content)) return;

  const [, matchedPrefix] = message.content.match(prefixRegex);

  const args = message.content.slice(matchedPrefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const command =
    client.commands.get(commandName) ||
    client.commands.find((cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

  if (!command) return;

  if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
    cooldowns.set(command.name, new Collection());
  }

  const now = Date.now();
  const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
  const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 1) * 1000;

  if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
    const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

    if (now < expirationTime) {
      const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
      return message.reply(`please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`);
    }
  }
  // Set the timestamp for the current command usage
  timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
  setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

  // Execute the command
  command.execute(message, args);

});
```

notice that the major changes are at the end of the code.